# Positioning of Content Relative to Background

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am new to HTML and CSS and have been struggling with a simple problem. I am designing a music space: http://theparadisegarage.co/ , and I am trying to position the main text box so that the text "disappears" (ie ends) behind the crate in the same place. In reality, the text box changes location depending on the window size. I have tried setting the position to absolute and giving it a fixed (px) margin on the bottom, but it doesn't seem to work. To give you an idea of the basic location that I would like the text box, I positioned the textbox with respect to the top of the browser window (because that seems to work for some reason). I have included relavent CSS. I am stumped... thank you in advance for any help!

```
    <html>
      <body style="background-color:transparent">
        <div id="container" style="background-color:transparent" >
          <div id="logo">

          </div>
          <div id="content" style="float:left" >

          </div>
          <div id="navbar" style="position:fixed">

         </div>
       </div>

     </body>
    </html>


    body{
        width: 100%;     
        height: 100%;     
        margin: 0;     
        padding: 0;
    background-image:url(paradisebackground6.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    }


    container {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
    }

    content{    
       position:relative;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   margin-top:12.5%;
   margin-left:190px;
   margin-right:auto;
   width:625px;
   height:372px;
   overflow:auto;
   z-index:-40
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you figured it out? Use z-index to position elements in front or behind other elements.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried creating a foreground (crate) and background (record sleeves), but when i placed the foreground "over" the text, it wouldn't let me scroll anymore.

Answer (score 0):

when you use POSITION in css, that's better that use top/bottom/right/left instead of margins:

```
#content{

   position:relative;
   top:12.5%;
   left:190px;

   width:625px;
   height:372px; 

}
```

notice: you must use # before css selector!!!